# create and download pdf in codeigniter

Tags: php

I am using codeigniter and creating a functionality for generate and dwonload pdf.
when i implement it on local host its working very fine. 
but its not working on live server (its not taking array(width=>550).
I am in hurry please help me Thanks in advance
Here is my code please check it

```
public function invoice_pfd(){


        $this->load->library('cezpdf');
        $this->load->helper('pdf');

        prep_pdf(); // creates the footer for the document we are creating.
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Doe', 'phone' => '111-222-3333', 'email' => 'jdoe@someplace.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jane Doe', 'phone' => '222-333-4444', 'email' => 'jane.doe@something.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Smith', 'phone' => '333-444-5555', 'email' => 'jsmith@someplacepsecial.com');


        $col_names = array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'phone' => 'Phone Number',
            'email' => 'E-mail Address'
        );

        $this->cezpdf->ezTable($db_data, $col_names, 'My Invoice', array('width' => 1550 ));
        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();

        //$data['social'] = $this->Business_model->social_data();

    }
```

Comment: Do you have error ? something we can work on ?

Comment: No there is not any error its working fine but its not taking width.

Comment: Follow this tutorial - http://christophermonnat.com/blog/generating-pdf-files-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

This might help you ..

```
<?php
    function tables()
    {
        $this->load->library('cezpdf');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Doe', 'phone' => '111-222-3333', 'email' => 'jdoe@someplace.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jane Doe', 'phone' => '222-333-4444', 'email' => 'jane.doe@something.com');
        $db_data[] = array('name' => 'Jon Smith', 'phone' => '333-444-5555', 'email' => 'jsmith@someplacepsecial.com');
        $col_names = array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'phone' => 'Phone Number',
            'email' => 'E-mail Address'
        );
        $this->cezpdf->ezTable($table_data, $col_names, 'Contact List', array('width'=>550));
        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
    }
?>
```

This is not based on your question. but it can might help you .

For more info [click here](http://christophermonnat.com/blog/generating-pdf-files-using-codeigniter) 
This another library is also helpful, [Check here](http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrate-ezpdf-a-k-a-pdf-php-into-codeigniter-framework/)